# How to get what excel cell is showing?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a strange question.

Screenshot:

[image: sample data]

From the screenshot you can see that the formula bar is showing just a single apostrophe. This is on all of the blue cells. These should be dates but all this data is coming from a excel plugin (Board)

From what I know Excel treats this cells differently i.e. everything after the apostrophe should be shown as text but here there is nothing after the apostrophe and the cells are still showing a values.

Is there a way with formula that I can get and compare this value with another cell in different worksheet?

EDIT:
If there is a way to get it as a text, could it be than converted into date format number?

EDIT 2 - SOLUTION
As per Mahesh and Jeeped comments - there was a newline character in the formula bar

Comment: What value is the cell showing? `'`?

Comment: Most probably there's a newline after the apostrophe, which is forcing the actual date to be shown below. Press `Ctrl + Shift + U` to expand the formula bar. You'll be able to see it.

Comment: Open the formula bar vertically. I'm pretty sure you have a line feed then the date. e.g. `'&CHAR(10)&23/10/2017`

Comment: omg, never thought of that. Thanks guys, there was a new line in the formula bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date is preceded only by a new line and there are no other characters after the date, this will be much simpler:

```
=VALUE(REPLACE(A1,1,1,""))
```

This will give you the date value in general format (i.e., 43033), so you'll have to format it as a date.

*Note:* Using `DATEVALUE` instead of `VALUE` will give you the same result.

Comment: I think the actual cell also includes a trailing vbLF and a 17.

Comment: @Jeeped, If that's the case, then my formula will fail. I've offered this simpler one only in case there is nothing after the date. Yours will, of course, work. +1

Comment: Yeah, we are kind of working on assumptions and some speculation here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I should've explain better. the "17" is a part of "24/10/2017" and not enough space to be on one line.

Comment: Both formulas is working for me, I'll decide later which one I'm going to use. Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1):

You have not confirmed the vbLF characters in the cells but try this in an unused cell  to retrieve a true date.

```
=datevalue(trim(mid(substitute(kn1, char(10), rept(char(32), len(kn1))), len(kn1), len(kn1))))
```

Assuming that you are on a DMY regional format that should get you a number like 43028. Format it as a date.

Comment: I'll try in a sec and let you know

Comment: Anyway, I need to compare it with another cells so it doesn't really matter how it is formatted. Just needed to get rid of text formatted.

Comment: What significance does the *17* play and is it also in the same cell separated by a second vbLF?

Comment: Err, *17* is part of *2017* (this year)

Comment: No, that's just not enough space to show in the cell so the 2017 went into the second line

Comment: OK, I get it now. You know, you could easily turn those into true dates with the same format if you could make the font smaller or widen the column to show the date in one line.